# ViewPager rendering BIG and unexplainable issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

An image better many words :

[image: ViewPager without a PagerAdapter]

[image: Login screen, all messed up]

[image: Third fragment, same]

My (fairly simple) code :

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends FragmentActivity {
…
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private SplashPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        mPager = ((ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager));
        mPagerAdapter = new SplashPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
…
    }
```

With a simple Activity layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

On a Nexus 5, with Fragment Support Library.

My fragments are rendering nicely in the fake edit view of Eclipse :

[image: Eclipse's fake view of my fragment]

Anyone that encountered this problem… I need help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was the theme set on my Activity (custom `@style/Theme.NoBackground`) in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

The background of the app was transparent …